# date_trunc month returning timestamp with timezone in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Initial table

```
id date
1  2021-01-01 00:00
2 2020-03-26 00:00
3 2019-05-16 00:00
```

The date datatype is `text`

I would like to change the date into month

```
id month
1 01/2021
2 03/2020
3 05/2019
```

The query I tried,

```
select id, date_trunc('month',date)::date as date_month
from schema.table t
```

Returns

```
ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, text) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the column date to timestamp to use it in date_trunc.  Like this:

```
select id, date_trunc('month',date::timestamp)::date as date_month from schema.table t
```

If you only want to use the result as text, you can simply do:

```
select id, to_char(date::timestamp,'mm/YYYY') as date_month from schema.table t
```

Comment: thanks. How can I remove the date from the month? I know that the last two numbers will always be 01, but it will be nice if I can get rid of the 01?
so, instead of '2021-01-01', '2021-01'

Comment: I updated the answer to return text field with only month and year.

Comment: can I use the format mm/YYYY but keep the variable datatype as datetime?

Comment: No you cannot.  A timestamp has day, month, year + time part.  Date has the datepart.  You can format it the way you like but you cannot change the primitive type.